# Git status correctness with submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I just added mysql-server as a submodule to my project.

Then I switch from the current "master" to the release I will be using for my development with

```
git checkout tags/mysql-8.0.27
```

Now, before committing I tried to see what I'm about to commit.

Turns out I will push .gitmodules, mysql-server/ and then I see:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   mysql-server (new commits)
```

Why is that? Will this be gone after committing? Or I should add this to the staging?

Please advise.

EDIT:

Just to clear things up.

In my repository I did:

```
ls -la                          # toget the list of stuff
git submodule add mysql-server # full URL skipped for clarity
cd mysql-server                 # nothing committed as of yet and nothing is added to commit
git checkout tags/mysql-8.0.27  # this checkout last commit in the 8.0.27 series
cd ..                           # I'm ready to add and commit because I want to work with that specific TAG
git status
```

At this point I see 2 things in the staging - `.gitmodules` and mysql-server directory. AND I also see the mysql-server directory with the message above.

After performing those commands I see in the status:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   .gitmodules
    new file:   mysql-server

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   mysql-server (new commits)
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214879/273817

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: the fact that you ran this `git checkout` *in the submodule* is crucial information.  I assumed you ran this `git checkout` *in the superproject*.  Most of the original answer is therefore wrong; let me revise it.  I'll leave it in since the original *question* still implies the original answer.

#### New answer

You now say that you ran:

```
git submodule add <url> mysql-server
```

*in your superproject*, and then ran `git checkout tags/mysql-8.0.27` *in the submodule*.  Using your updated question and some comments below, I have created a minimal reproducible example as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh -e

# create reproducer repo; create an initial commit
# and make the branch name be "master" for consistency
# with the original question.
mkdir repro
cd repro
git init
echo test submodule example on stackoverflow > README
git add README
git commit -m initial
git branch -m master

# add submodule, using its current master/main/whatever branch
# as the commit to be selected
git submodule add https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server.git mysql-server 

# switch the submodule to the commit selected by tag mysql-8.0.27
(cd mysql-server && git checkout tags/mysql-8.0.27)

# observe status
git status
```

Running this produces (I've snipped various sections for brevity, replacing them with `...`):

```
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
...
Updating files: 100% (8402/8402), done.
Note: switching to 'tags/mysql-8.0.27'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. ...

HEAD is now at 3290a66c89e 
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   .gitmodules
        new file:   mysql-server

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   mysql-server (new commits)
```

If you'd like your *superproject* to record this as the *desired* commit, you simply need to move back to the superproject and run:

```
git add mysql-server
```

to update the *gitlink* in the index/staging-area for the superproject, and then `git commit` to store the `.gitmodules` and chosen gitlink hash ID in a new commit.  Since my script leaves me above the superproject, I did that by hand like this:

```
$ cd repro
$ git add mysql-server
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   .gitmodules
    new file:   mysql-server

$ [master c472e53] add myqsl-server submodule using v8.0.27
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 160000 mysql-server
```

Cloning and checking out the superproject (with `--recursive` to also clone and check out the submodule, or followed by `git submodule update --init`) will also clone and check out the `tags/mysql-8.0.27` commit in the submodule.

#### Original question's answer

> ```
> git checkout tags/mysql-8.0.27
> ```

Since you didn't run `git checkout --recursive` (and presumably don't have recursive checkout set as your *default* either), this updated your current commit in your superproject *only*.

The commit you selected (via `tags/mysql-8.0.27`) calls for some particular submodule commit.  I don't know the actual hash ID; let me make up a fake one.  I'll say that it calls for `b777777`.  (It's possible that it does not call for any; in that case, you'll have to decide whether "remove the submodule entirely" is the correct thing, or "add the submodule" is the correct thing.)

Earlier, when you set up the submodule, you cloned and checked out some commit.  I don't know the actual hash ID; let me make up a fake one.  I'll say that you *currently* have `a123456` checked out *in the submodule*.

Well, *you still have `a123456` checked out in the submodule*.  That is, after all, a completely different Git repository.  Sure, it's a submodule.  But that just means that the superproject will look at it now and then.  It was, is, and always will be a *completely different Git repository*, with its own commits and branch and tag names and checkout and so on.

The *superproject* is now calling for some particular commit.  The *submodule* isn't *on* that commit.  So `git status`, run *in the superproject*, says:

> ```
> Changes not staged for commit:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
>   (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
>         modified:   mysql-server (new commits)
> ```

which means "the submodule is not on the commit that the superproject says it should be on".

Who's right?  Who's wrong?  Which commit *should* the submodule be on?  That's for you to decide.  You pick the right commit.  You can use the hash ID called for by the superproject.  You can use the hash ID that's in the submodule right now.  You can run `git log` in the submodule and poke around until you find some particular commit you like.  Pick some commit and run `*git checkout hash-id` and you now have that commit checked out in the submodule.

The superproject's commit calls for some hash ID (I made it up above, let's repeat it now: `b777777`).  You could pick *that* one and `git checkout b777777` (but of course `b777777` is probably not the right hash ID, and might not even be a valid one, since I made it up).  If you do check out that particular commit, as the superproject commit asks you to, `git status` run *in* the superproject Git repository will stop saying this thing about the submodule.

If that's not the right commit, though, it's up to you to find the right commit, and check that one out.  You can then `git add` the submodule path *in* the superproject, to record what *is* the right hash ID (according to whatever process you used to determine that), and run `git commit` *in* the superproject to make a new commit that calls for that hash ID.

If the superproject already calls for the right hash ID, use `git checkout` in the submodule with that hash ID.  Or have Git do it for you, with any of these:

```
git submodule update
```

or:

```
git rev-parse :mysql-server
```

(a commit hash ID will pop out) and then:

```
(cd mysql-server && git checkout <hash-id>)
```

(put in the hash ID that came out from the `git rev-parse`), or:

```
git checkout --recursive tags/mysql-8.0.27
```

(this has your superproject Git run `git submodule update --recursive` for you; that's all the `--recursive` really does here).

#### `git submodule status` is sometimes helpful too

Consider running `git submodule status` to see both the current and called-for commit, for each submodule listed in the superproject.  Consider running `git submodule summary` as well.  The information these dump out is in Git's usual cryptic form, unfortunately, and submodules are called sob-modules for good reason.  But that's basically it: it's all about figuring out which commit to use from each submodule.

Comment: IIUC, the main project and the submodule `mysql-server` are looking at the different commit, hence the message I referenced. Am I right? Now in the beginning all I did was to issue `git submodule add`. Then I went to the mysql-server subdirectory and issued the `git checkout tag/mysql-8.0.27`. I think that this command make my current commit to become the one that has this tag applied. And in the submodule I'm looking at this commit. But my main project doesn't know about that and still think I'm in the master branch in that submodule.

Comment: if that is true and the commands you provided will update that - so that my main project will think my mysql repo is at the tag I selected - that's all I need. I will ust issue `git submodule update`, which will update my project internals to be in par with the subproect of mysql and then commit it. If I miss something - let me know. TIA!!

Comment: Now, of course if I'm mistaken and I still need to actually do `git checkout <HASH__ID>` in the submodule directory - please also let me know.

Comment: Aha: the fact that you did the `git checkout` *in* the submodule is a key item you left out of your original question. The `git submodule add` you did in the superproject created and registered `.gitmodules` for commit, and registered the *current commit* in the submodule as the "correct" commit. You must then have run `git commit` to commit the `.gitmodules` and gitlink (hash ID). Let me update my answer.

Comment: I just read your `New Answer`. Let me re-iterate. What I did was: `cd <my_main_project>` && `git submodule add mysql-server` && `cd mysql-server` && `git checkout tags/mysql-8.0.27`. I didn't commit anything anywhere during this 4 commands. Now I'm ready to commit. My mysql submodule is at the right commit and my main project is on master..

Comment: However, doing `git status` I found I have something uncommitted. Like I said - I presume that the main project and my mysql subproject are not in sync AFA git is concerned, because of the `git checkout` command I ran in the submodule tree.

Comment: If I'm right - all I need is fix it so that they will be in sync and commit.

Comment: You must have snipped the `changes staged for commit` (`.gitmodules` at the least).  Well, I *think* `git submodule add` does a `git add` on `.gitmodules`, and if it didn't that too should have been in `changes not staged for commit`. But yes, you just need to get all the pieces into synchrony and commit.

Comment: no`.gitmodules` file is staged.

Comment: Is it *unstaged* then? Because `git submodule add` has to create/modify `.gitmodules`. I tried a `git submodule add` in a temporary throwaway repository; `git status` now shows `Changes to be committed:` including `new file:  .gitmodules`.

Comment: By the way, note that this kind of confusion and back-and-forth would be completely eliminated with a [mre]. (That's why [ask] recommends providing one.)

Comment: it is staged to be committed. AND it has some commits unstaged. Try this - after you do `git submodule add sub`. `cd sub && git checkout <SHA!>`. Then do `cd .. && git status`. You will see what I see - 2 thingsfor the directory and staged `.gitmodules` file.

Comment: also please see my edit - I added the commands I used as I did exactly. Follow it and you will get the results I see.

Comment: OK - yes, I stand by my revised answer: just `git add mysql-server` and `git status` will go back to two things staged for commit and nothing unstaged.

Comment: did you try it? Because I can send you a screenshot of what I see...

Comment: I can't try it without a true [mre]. If you skip steps, there's nothing for me to try. (I note that you have a typo, `git submodules ...` should be `git submodule`, but I'd also need the URL for the mysql repo, and to be a reproducible example you'll need some initial `git init`, `git add`, `git commit` steps to make a repository in which you can `git submodule add` the mysql repo.)

Comment: the full URL is https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server.git. And you can use any repo as a parent.

Comment: Also, that was a typo that I fixed and I added the result of running the last `git status`...

Comment: All good now - I've edited again with my [mre].